# How can I create a edge based on the name of existing edge between 2 nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 nodes

[image]

How to create an edge named "Son" from "Ben" to "John" if the existing relation is "Father" and "Ben's Gender is 'Male" like below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (f:Person)-[:Father]->(s:Person)
WHERE s.name = 'Ben' AND s.Gender = 'Male'
CREATE (s)-[:Son]->(f)
```

If it is possible that the `Son` relationship already exists, you should use [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) instead of [CREATE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/create/) to avoid creating a duplicate relationship.

You may also want to consider simplifying your data model (and reducing the storage size of your DB) by not adding the redundant `Son` relationship at all, since you can already tell that `Ben` is the son of `John` by using the above `MATCH` and `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: How to add a condition to create edge only if doesn't exists, whether CREATE UNIQUE helps?

Comment: @hanzgs You can use [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/), as already mentioned in my answer. You should read its documentation fully, as `MERGE` can be tricky to get right.